# Docker install on armv7

Tags: docker, arm, debian, installation

I am having trouble with my docker installation.
I rent a arm storage server for my setup.
The kernel is 
  `4.5.2-armada375 #1 SMP Tue Oct 25 11:52:56 CEST 2016 armv7l`

But when i try to insall docker-ce and the other packages ive got the following error:

```
Jul 09 20:54:50 storage-fr systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 09 20:54:50 storage-fr systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 09 20:54:50 storage-fr systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17024-1) ...
Setting up rename (0.20-4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/file-rename to provide /usr/bin/rename (rename) in auto mode
Setting up aufs-dkms (4.9+20161219-1) ...
Loading new aufs-4.9+20161219 DKMS files...
It is likely that 4.5.2-armada375 belongs to a chroot's host
```

I think the kernel is not compatible.
IS it possible to install docker on it?

I tried this guide https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/

But it doesnt work.

Any idea ?